# VB.NET Dim screen other then the form

Tags: vb.net, screen

Okay so I am developing a screen capturing program.

At the moment I have it creating a rectangle and taking a screenshot of that.. although the rectangle is a bright red line, i'd like to somehow DIM the screen that is outside of the rectangle.

I was thinking to do this with maybe another form.. but not sure if this would be the best way.

Thanks.

Comment: You could 'colour' the whole screen except the area covered by the rectangle with a shade of colour that is slightly transparent - an opacity of say 80%... http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/

Comment: @Mych How would I do this?